# Merging by range of numbers

Tags: merge, range, sas

I'd like to assign a person's name to a number based on a range rather than an explicit number. It's possible to do this using formats, but as I have the names in a dataset I'd prefer to avoid the manual process of writing the `proc format`.

```
data names;                      
   input low high name $;  
   datalines;
1   10  John
11  20  Paul
21  30  George
31  40  Ringo
;

data numbers;
    input number;
    datalines;
33
21
17
5
;
```

The desired output is:

```
data output;
    input number name $;
    datalines;
33  Ringo
21  George
17  Paul
5   John
;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this using PROC SQL:

```
proc sql;
 create table output as
 select numbers.number, names.name
 from numbers left join names
  on numbers.number ge names.low
  and numbers.number le names.high
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

One handy feature of `proc format` is the ability to use a data set to create the format, instead of typing it in by hand.  Your scenario seems like a perfect scenario for this feature.

In the example you give, a few small changes to the "names" data set will put it in a form that can be read by proc format.

For example, if I modify the names data set like so..

```
data names;
   retain fmtname "names" type "N";
   input start end label $; 
   datalines;
1   10  John
11  20  Paul
21  30  George
31  40  Ringo
;
```

I can then issue this command to build the format based on it.

```
proc format cntlin=names;run;
```

Now I can use this format just like you would with any other format.  For example, to create a new column that contains the desired "name" based on the number, you could do this:

```
data numbers;
    input number;
    number_formatted=put(number,names.);
    datalines;
33
21
17
5
;
```

Here is what the output would look like:

```
             number_
  number    formatted

    33       Ringo
    21       George
    17       Paul
     5       John
```

---

**Update to address question:**

There isn't much difference in coding needed to read from a text file.  We just need to set it up so that the output data set has the particular variable names that proc format expects (fmtname, type, start, end , and label).

For example, if I have an external comma-seperated file called "names.csv" that looks like this:

```
1,10,John
11,20,Paul
21,30,George
31,40,Ringo
```

Then I simply can change the code that creates the "names" data set so that it looks like this:

```
data names;
   retain fmtname "names" type "N";
   infile "<path to file>/names.csv" dsd;
   input start end label $;
run;
```

Now I can run proc format with the cntlin option like I did before:

```
proc format cntlin=names;run;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I suspected there would a way to use a dataset as a format. One problem however; I have the format dataset in an external csv which I can read to a SAS dataset quite fine, but I've not been able to create the format from the dataset, only using the 'datalines' method. Can you suggest code to create the format using an existing SAS dataset?

Comment: Great, that was the problem. Just needed the correct variables names 'start, end, & label'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL is more succinct indeed, but if you aren't big fan of it and the numbers come in known increments, you may try something like:

```
data ranges;
    set names;
    do number = low to high; /* by ... */
        output;
    end;
proc sort;
    by number;
run;

data output;
    merge ranges
        numbers ( in = innum )
    ;
    by number;
    keep number name;

    if innum;
run;
```

Again, it requires numbers to come in predetermined increments, e.g. integers.

Comment: Great to have a non SQL alternative.